# React.js - removeEvent() in useEffect() hook

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, use-effect

I'm trying to get the HTML5 audio element to autoplay on page load. I know that Chrome doesn't allow autoplay by default, unless something triggers it. So I've created a couple of event listeners within the `useEffect()` hook:

```
const Audio = () => {
  const audioPlayer = document.getElementById('myAudio')
  const playAudio = () => audioPlayer.play()
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', playAudio)
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', playAudio)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', playAudio)
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', playAudio)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <audio
      id="myAudio"
      src={ audioAssetHere }
    />
  )
}
```

This does work but it keeps playing every time the cursor moves. I only want it to play once. I also get this error in the console:

```
DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first
```

And yet the audio still works every time the cursor moves.

I also tried using `useRef` and assign it to the audio tag `ref={audioRef}`, and then used it within the `useEffect` hook:

```
const audioRef = useRef()
const playAudio = () => audioRef.current.play()
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', playAudio)
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', playAudio)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', playAudio)
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', playAudio)
    }
  }, [])
```

This gives the error:

```
TypeError: audioRef.current.play is not a function
```

So in a nutshell, what I want is the audio to play every time the page loads. And I only want it to play once.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to play audio on every mousemove/scroll event, instead of it you just need to play it once on the first mousemove/scroll event:

```
const Audio = () => {
  const audioRef = React.useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const playAudio = () => {
      audioRef.current.play();
      removeListeners()
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', playAudio)
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', playAudio)
    
    const removeListeners = () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', playAudio)
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', playAudio)
    }
    
    return () => {
      removeListeners()
    }
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <audio
      src={ audioAssetHere }
      ref={ audioRef }
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer. It works. Just one caveat, I still get this error in the console when the page first loads: DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first. The audio works though.